# Make a Border Bigger Around a JButton

Tags: java, swing, border

I'm making a User Interface for a small program idea I had and I am using Swing to create it.

I have a BoxLayout with four JButtons in it - but the problem I'm having is that for some reason changing the dimensions of the JButton doesn't make any difference, which I suppose also changes the border size. The border wraps around the button with no space, and I don't know how to change its dimensions. The only way I can make the JButton bigger is by changing the font size (I'm using a custom font), but the border still wraps around - which  I don't want. 
So my main questions is - how do I change the dimensions of the border so it doesn't stick to the text? **Note** - I **do not** want to change the **thickness** of the border.

Here is my code:

```
private static void contentGUI(Container pane) throws IOException, FontFormatException {

    Font customFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new 
    File("customfont.ttf")).deriveFont(30f);
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont(customFont);

    Border borderVar = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 3);

    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JButton task1 = new JButton(" > Advanced CPU Settings");
    task1.setFont(customFont);
    task1.setBorder(borderVar);
    task1.setBorderPainted(true);
    task1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    task1.setFocusPainted(false);
  
    pane.add(task1);
}
```

Run result:
[image: This is what happens when I run it, which is everything I desire, except for the border]

Comment: 1) One way is to use a [`CompoundBorder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html). E.G. a combination of an `EmptyBorder` and the current (line) border. 2) `new File("misc/Ac437_IBM_EGA_8x8.ttf")` Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL..

Comment: .. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you @AndrewThompson, the CompoundBorder works fine. I have edited my code to keep as much as is useful.

Comment: *"the CompoundBorder works fine."* Glad you got it sorted. now you might answer the question below, or deleted the question using the link below the tags. *"I have edited my code to keep as much as is useful."* While brevity is one aspect of an **M**RE or **S**SCCE is important, an uncompilable code snippet does not satisfy the other requirements. Please read the documents carefully.

Comment: BTW *"as much as is useful.."* ..for what, exactly? It would seem that setting the focus painting, BG and FG colors, text alignment and font have nothing to do with the problem. Seriously, read *both* those links *carefully* in order to better understand how to write code demonstrating a problem that people can work with, without *any* changes, additions or irrelevant code lines.

Comment: Sure yeah, @Andrew Thompson, since I didn’t know what the problem was I just kept whatever was related to the decoration of the button just in case any of them had something to do with the border error.

Comment: *"since I didn’t know what the problem was"* Comment out the code line, is the problem still evident? If so, the line is unnecessary. This is all explained in the documents you did not read, so minus one.